# get button to appear no matter how far you scroll down excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, alignment, worksheet

In my excel document I want the button to appear no matter how far I scroll down. I don't know if there is a way to pin the button so that when I scroll down the button still appears. I dont want to scroll up all the way up to click the button. I added a photo if that makes things clearer.

[image: excelSheet]

Comment: Put it on a modeless UserForm instead?

Comment: Freeze panes and put the button at the top? Then you also keep the headers visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom tab on the ribbon with the macro you want to run. Unfortunately, there is not a way to pin a button in place, unless you use a userform per Tim Williams suggestion. I created a custom ribbon tab to get around this hassle.

[image]